# How to create a fog for baclgro6 which works on mobile devices?

Tags: unity, android, shaders, mobile, fog

There is a forum entry, which explains how to create a high based volumetric fog, using soft particles ( [How can I create a height-based volumetric fog?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143382/how-can-i-create-a-height-based-volumetric-fog/175435#) ). Unfortunately it doesn't work on mobile devices. Does anyone know a solution, how to create this effect which can be used for mobile?

Comment: There are a few ways we can approach this, depending on your situation. If you have not too many objects in your scene, then it might be efficient enough to ask Unity to render a depth buffer you can sample as a texture and blend your fog plane based on this depth value. If you have a lot of objects in your scene / a lot of overdraw, this could get more expensive. But if all the objects that need to be obscured by fog use one material, you could build the fog into their shader to render it along with the object in one pass. Can you show us what your typical scene looks like / should look like?

Comment: It is a row of cube shaped objects, which form a wall. The direction of the wall is random. There are ten of the cube gameobjects visible at the same time. Soon the objects, which are not visible will be destroyed. So there are not so many objects at the same time.